# TYPO3 sysext form: get value of selected radio button

Tags: forms, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have created a simple form with three radio buttons and one submit button.

[image]

The radio buttons have integers as value

```
Value of Radio Button #1:   40
Value of Radio Button #2:   41
Value of Radio Button #3:   42
```

If the user selects radio button #1 for example and presses the submit button, then he should be redirected to the page with ID 40.

How can i find out which of the radio buttons is selected and get the value of it? I tried it like this `GP:assistent:group1`

**Whole form configuration:**

```
title = test
enctype = application/x-www-form-urlencoded
method = post
prefix = assistent
confirmation = 
postProcessor {
    1 = redirect
    1 {
        destination = GP:assistent:group1
    }
}
10 = RADIOGROUP
10 {
    class = fieldset-subgroup
    legend {
        value = Nächste Schritte
    }
    name = group1
    10 = RADIO
    10 {
        checked = checked
        type = radio
        value = 40
        label {
            value = Ich habe ein Problem mit X
        }
    }
    20 = RADIO
    20 {
        type = radio
        value = 41
        label {
            value = Ich habe ein Problem mit Y
        }
    }
    30 = RADIO
    30 {
        type = radio
        value = 42
        label {
            value = Ich habe ein Problem mit Z
        }
    }
}
20 = SUBMIT
20 {
    type = submit
    name = 6
    value = Weiter
}
```

Comment: It seems to be impossible, so i created a workaround with javascript

Comment: At the moment, the destination attribute of the redirect postProcessor is not stdWrap-able (see [code][1]). Your idea is great but that way it will not work. One solution is to write your own postProcessor. If you're interested I can have a look. Furthermore, I recommend streamlining your form since it constains some strange settings.


  [1]: https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/form/Classes/PostProcess/RedirectPostProcessor.php#L68

Comment: Thank you! I think writing my own post processor exceeds my programming abilities. I already created a good workaround with javascript. It is a simple script which gets the value of the selected radio button and redirects the user to it with `window.location.replace`. 
I also replaced the submit button with a normal button. I only have to include this script in every page which uses forms.

Comment: Here's an example how to write your own postProcessor: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/34241#change-307483. Anyway, you're solution is okay and does the job.

Comment: Thank you, i will read into it.

Answer (score -1):

one solution is to add your Form and grep the GP Parameter. "LOAD_REGISTER" like

```
page.1=TEXT
page.1.value (
<form method="get" action="">
<ul>
<li><input type="radio" name="myid" value="20" /></li>
<li><input type="radio" name="myid" value="30" /></li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" value="Dummy text">
</form>
)

[globalVar = GP:myid >0]
page.jsInline {
     1234 = TEXT
     #1234.dataWrap = alert("redirect to:'Location: index.php?id={GP:nameradio}'");
     1234.value = window.location.assign("index.php?id={GP:myid}")
     1234.insertData=1
}
#or with config.additionalHeaders
[global]
```

keep things simple.

regards
Pete

Comment: The solution is an easier approach but does not answer the specific question. EdwardBlack is using the form extension. You're approach is simple HTML.

Comment: This was for testing only, anyway works. In this case change page.1 to page.1=FORM {..config..{10=TEXTLINE ..}}.